# How to duplicate a certain number of values and then change to another in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dataset

Hi guys I am trying to expand an existing dataset but I don't know exactly what I have to do. 
For example I got this set of values in excel cloumn A:

```
21
45
77
```

I need more observations in column B, so I would like 4 observations of the same value and after excel should pass to the next original value and generate another 4 observations.
Something like this I mean:
[image]

Hope anyone can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data starts at `A1` then in `B1` use:
`=INDEX(A:A,(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A:A)*4)+3)/4)`
(Not sure if it requires `ctrl+shift+enter` for versions prior to office 365)
[image]

Comment: I think is not working because I can't drag the formula to the other cells. I am looking for a general formula to be used for a large amount of data. I don't know if is possible whit excel actually.

Comment: See my edit as an array-function, which will result in the desired range at once in office 365